# I need a readymade Tailwind template layout which divides the screen in left and right with responsive design

Tags: css, templates, next.js, tailwind-css

I am looking for a Tailwind template which divides the screen in two halves on a normal screen: left and right. It needs to be responsive so that it is also ux friendly on a small smartphone screen.

Background: I would like my user to select items in the left side so that is copied to the right side. This is similar to what an ecommerce website does: the product catalogue at the left side and the shopping cart at the right side. I want to use this in a Next.js implementation.

Preferably, I would like to download it as a readymade Tailwind template.

Please advise me where I can download such specific template.

Thank you